# How can we count combinations with repetition (or permutations) using inequality symbols between each number?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, permutations, combinations

Consider the set of $n = 4$ elements  $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ that correspond to positions A, B, C, D. Now, I want to set certain restrictions on the numbers I can choose for each position so I have included inequalities. See [Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IowIM.png) here:

Repetitions are allowed provided they do not contradict the inequality (as shown in the example).

Since there are 2 inequities used, $<$ and $\leq$, and 3 placements for them, there are a total of $2^3=8$ distinct patterns available. I have tried all $8$ and I noticed that any that make use of two $\leq$ and one $<$ (regardless of the order) make a table of **15 rows of permutations**. If the inequality patterns have one $\leq$ and two $<$ (again, regardless of order) it makes a table of **5 rows of permutations**. If there are three $<$ there is naturally only one permutation and if there are three $\leq$ it makes a table of **35 permutations**.

I have been saying *rows of permutations* since the order matters (as dictated by the inequalities), but is this correct? The number of permutations in each table appears to come from *combinations with repetitions*: $C^R_{1,4}=1$, $C^R_{2,4}=5$, $C^R_{3,4}=15$ and $C^R_{4,4}=35$.

One clue might be the *columns* of these tables. For instance, the columns of any table of five permutations includes only **two** *distinct* elements from **four** (and includes repetitions). This is the same as combinations with repetitions: $C^R_{2,4}=5$. Similarly, any table of $15$ elements has in its columns only **three** distinct elements **from** four This is the same as $C^R_{3,4}=15$. 
My questions are:

1. Are these row elements indeed permutations? If not, what is the correct term for them?
2. Is my idea of counting the perms in each table using $C^R_{n,r}$ correct? If so, how can I show this is true in general?
3. Is there a link between the inequality patterns (and the number , $n-1$, of them) and the number of perms in each table?